# Vida de una serpiente en JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy haciendo un "juego" de una serpiente, en la que debe de crecer poco a poco y que cada parte de su cuerpo tenga un color. Tengo problemas con meterle el color y no sé de que manera puedo introducirlo. Pongo el código que tengo puesto en el que me sale null. Mi idea era que mostrara en la última posición un color. Espero haberme explicado bien. Gracias de antemano

```
public class serpiente {

    private String[] serpiente;
    private int edad;

    public serpiente() {
        this.serpiente = new String[1];
        this.edad = 1;
    }

    public void colores() {
        String[] colores = {"blue, pink, green, yellow, red"};
        int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * colores.length);
        serpiente[serpiente.length-1]=colores[aleatorio];
    }

}
```

En index.jsp

```
serpiente manolita = new serpiente();
String[] mostrar = null;
mostrar= manolita.getSerpiente();

for (int i = 0; i < mostrar.length ; i++) {
    out.print(mostrar[i]);
}
```

Comment: Escribir código Java en un JSP es siempre una mala idea, deberías intentar evitarlo. Por otro lado deberías también intentar seguir las [convenciones de Java](https://javadesdecero.es/fundamentos/convenciones-nomenclatura-java/) y usar mayúsculas en la primera letra del identificador de clase

Comment: Ok, pero necesito que sea java en jsp.

Answer (score 2):

Parece que olvidaste llamar al método `colores()` en alguna parte.

Por ejemplo:

```
serpiente manolita = new serpiente();
manolita.colores();
```

Aún así, solo un segmento de la serpiente será coloreado.

Comment: Cierto! lo borré en algún momento. Mi idea era hacer lo que dices, que solo me meta un color e ir poniendole valores poco a poco, pero poniendole el método colores() me pinta todos los colores del vector y sólo necesito 1 en la última posición

Salida: blue, pink, green, yellow, red